# Reactive 2d canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, webgl

I'm working on a tool that has an underlying 3d spacial representation, but renders views of itself in 2d. There may be as many as 1000 shapes on the screen at once. I'm having trouble keeping the view in sync with the models, so I want to start using a reactive solution (like Konva for React), but it is not particularly performant.

Are there any reactive webgl or otherwise more performant solutions that allow me to have a state and reliably render a canvas that reflects that state? Or maybe I am just approaching this problem from the wrong direction?

Comment: You could build state and so on with javascript too. you really dont need react. its only how you program it to be. Show us your code and we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how performant you would like it to be.

I have build one 2d engine with canvas for my project with no lib. I have one main Component that renders the canvas itself. Then i use redux to draw. All the business logic is done on the reducers. For my, its pretty performant. Then i have one file to draw what the reducers derived.

So the flow is like.
Canvas.js -> actions -> reduxMiddlewares -> reducers -> Drawer.js